# Using Amazon Maps beside Google Maps in the same app

Tags: java, android

As the title says I'm already using Google Maps in my app and I also would like to use Amazon Maps in case of Kindle devices. AM and GM v1 uses the same interface technically. How can i solve it nicely that depending on the device I'm using I get the appropriate class type (e.g. com.google.android.maps.MapView or com.amazon.geo.maps.MapView) for every class?

So let's say I need the appropriate version of the MapView class depending on my device because I want to construct a MapView object. As I said AM and GM has the same classes and methods but they don't implement a common interface though which prevents me from using a factory I think.

edit:

I hope I don't have to 
if(gmaps) {
do something with gmaps objects
}
else if (amaps) {
do the same with amaps objects
}

As I said the problem I think is that the two API has the same classes, methods and everything but they don't actually implement a common interface which makes it hard for me do think up a nice solution. What do you think?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a design pattern named [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)

But the Amazon Maps API looks like it mimics Google Maps v1, not the much better v2.